# How to store password as encrypted in properties file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, encryption, properties

I am very new in Spring framework and I am using Spring framework to manage my database connections and so on. Applicaiton reads my db connection parameters from a property file. The thing I need is to store my connection password in property file as encrypted. 
Here is my datasource xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>file:${DBConfigFile}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource"   class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>3</value></property>
        <property name="minPoolSize"><value>3</value></property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>50</value></property>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>200</value></property>
        <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>1</value></property>
        <property name="maxStatements"><value>0</value></property>
        <property name="numHelperThreads"><value>3</value></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am thiking to write the password encrypted to property file and I am wondering if Spring can decrypt it with an algorithm automatically. Is it possible with configuration.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

As far I known Spring does not support this ability, but some other project may be helpfull:

- [Jasypt library](http://www.jasypt.org/) offers support for encrypted application configuration (and also integrates with Spring). See details: http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html
- [OWASP Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) provides [EncryptedProperties](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/EncryptedProperties.java) interfaces with [DefaultEncryptedProperties](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/crypto/DefaultEncryptedProperties.java) and [ReferenceEncryptedProperties](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/crypto/ReferenceEncryptedProperties.java) implementations which may be used in your application. See also: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_encrypt_a_properties_file

Answer (score 6):

I am using spring 4 and jasypt 1.9. Jasypt documentation does not provide explicit support for spring 4. I could not locate class named `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with `org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.2` dependency either.

I wrote a simple static encryption utility java class (this uses jasypt API).

```
public class EncryptionUtil {
    static PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = null;
    static {
        encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
        encryptor.setPoolSize(4); 
        //  There are various approaches to pull this configuration via system level properties. 
        encryptor.setPassword("parashar");
        encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");
    }

    public static String encrypt(String input) {
        return encryptor.encrypt(input);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedMessage) {
        return encryptor.decrypt(encryptedMessage);
    }

}
```

I used this utility to encrypt the passwords I intended to keep in my property files.

I then simply used spring EL to decrypt the properties back in my spring config xml.

```
<property name="password" value="#{T(amit.parashar.EncryptionUtil).decrypt('${db.password}')}" />
```

EDIT :
To answer on how to hide the encryption password  :

```
Use system args while bringing up your java process.
```

> for e.g. : java -Dwhatismyencpawd="parashar"

and  use it like

```
encryptor.setPassword(java.lang.System.getProperty("whatismyencpawd"));
```

This way only the app admin would know the password. This way password will be visible as part of ps command though on a UNIX box.

or You can configure and read from OS level environment variable as well.

Comment: I don't understand, now how will I secure "parashar" because if someone check the code and he/she can decrypt right?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make any sense, because if the Spring can decrypt it, then everybody else could too. This encryption will not make any difference, it doesn't protect anything. It gives only dangerous thing - false feeling of protection.

Maybe you could use some another way of the database authentication, e.g. MS SQL server allows use Windows Security instead of password authentication. The same for Postgres (it gives access by user account or using SSL certificates).

Comment: You are right but I mention about a private algorithm of Spring, not a public one. Thank you for your answer, I will search about ssl certification.

Comment: @tace Private algorithm for security is oxymoron. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity . So, the one way to make it right is to use operation system protection (Windows NTLM, Unix pam, etc), it could provide some protection.

Comment: With encrypted credentials in your properties you can keep them version controlled (not together with private key obviously) together with the service that needs them, and automatically deployed when deploying the service. The only thing that needs to be maintained outside of the deploy pipeline is the private key for decrypting the properties, which should be far less error prone than maintaining the whole configuration outside of the normal life cycle of the service.

Comment: @SebastianGanslandt If you able to safely maintain a private key file in your system, then why do you need it then after all? What difference does it make? I think that it just makes the whole thing more difficult - you need to maintain the keys, introduce a safe procedure to change passwords, and add this special magic Spring configuration. KISS. In our project we have an external "security.properties" file which defines all sensitive information and never leaves the deployment target servers.

Comment: That was actually h solution I was thinking about before wandering of to encrypted properties which seemed a bit more elegant when the idea of a built in spring support still lived.

Comment: Just to defend the private key, that would be handled just like your security.properties so there not really more complexity involved in getting it on to the application servers. And you get a nice separation of the conent, which is all in one place (although encrypted) and the mechanics of reading them. Encrypting them I don't really see like an issue... But still, security.properties on the target servers or deploy jump station is probably the simplest solution. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @SebastianGanslandt The complexity is not getting it to the servers, but it is all around infrastructure. You need somehow introduce a tooling to encrypt the files. You need to maitnain them in source (moreover, they are meaningless here! What's a point to put something in a source control which you cannot read or write?) You'll have a problem of choosing encryption algorithms and it may attract attention of Auditors. Also, it reduces security: not sharing a secret is always most reliable solution, in comparison with a shared encrypted secret! So many disadvantages - and no benefits at all!

Comment: They important part is to keep the key separate from the code. The key should be provided in an environment variable or manually typed in upon boot. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49725/is-it-really-secure-to-store-api-keys-in-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [encryption and decryption](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption) provided by spring cloud config

Comment: OK, but how? That page appears to describe how to use the spring cloud client and server to receive decrypted properties from the config server.  But I have no interest in maintaining a service just to handle decrypting properties, so how do I pull the decryption mechanism for properties into a normal spring application context?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a bean that decrypts your password and then inject the bean into whatever needs the password

Comment: is there a way t inject in pom.xml?